# Setting environment variables in Gradle

Tags: gradle

I am using the tomcat plugin to start Tomcat server using a war file i have built using the war plugin.

Before the app starts i need to set some environment variables.
Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see in the Gradle Tomcat plugin docs, the plugin runs Tomcat in the Gradle process. Environment variables for that process can only be set from outside Gradle, in a manner appropriate for your environment/OS. Alternatively, you might want to look into the Gradle Cargo and Gradle Arquillian plugins, which can also run containers in an external process.

PS: Please don't double-post here and on http://forums.gradle.org.